# Bang methods in Groovy

Tags: methods, groovy

Does Groovy have something similar to bang methods on Ruby?

From [this blog post](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist):

> In Ruby, you can write methods whose names end in ! (exclamation point or “bang”). There’s a lot of confusion surrounding the matter of when, and why, you would want to do so.
>
> The ! in method names that end with ! means, “This method is dangerous”—or, more precisely, this method is the “dangerous” version of an otherwise equivalent method, with the same name minus the !. “Danger” is relative; the ! doesn’t mean anything at all unless the method name it’s in corresponds to a similar but bang-less method name.*

And [this site](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/writing_own_ruby_methods.html):

> You'll find a number of pairs of methods, one with the bang and one without. Those without the bang perform an action and return a freshly minted object, reflecting the results of the action (capitalizing a string, sorting an array, and so on). The bang versions of the same methods perform the action, but they do so in place: Instead of creating a new object, they transform the original object.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a convention in Groovy like it is in Ruby.  However you can write methods with names that contain characters like `!` with the limitation that it must always be quoted like a string:

```
// define method with quoted name
def 'dangerous!'() {
    // do something dangerous
}

// invoke method with quoted name
'dangerous!'()
```

Comment: I exactly tried that but when calling I did not use string, so I did not answer. Thanks you did. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, groovy (currently as of v2.1.4) doesn't have anything like this

Answer (score 1):

To add to your options, another solution that would be more Groovy-like or Java-like would be to include an optional parameter that enabled in-place (a.k.a. dangerous) modification, like so:

```
def processFoo(Foo item, mutate = false) {
    if(!mutate) {
        Foo temp = new Foo()
        // copy item properties
        item = temp
    }
    item.bar = 'blah blah'
    // process item here
    return item
}

processFoo(myFoo) // makes a copy
processFoo(myFoo, true) // modifies original
```

This pattern is used — albeit in the opposite manner — with the [sort](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28boolean%29) method on collections.  Calling `sort(false)` on `List`s prevents changing the original array.  Calling `sort()` or `sort(true)` will modify it directly.